# Issue with Multiple Intersects

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

My query is as follows -

I have a table with 2 columns  `Name` and `Mobile Number`.

Eg.

```
    [Name]: A, A, B, C, A, D, D, E, and so on
    [Mobile Number]: 1,1,2,2,4,3 and so on
```

One `Name` can have many mobile numbers.

I need to find all the mobile numbers which are in common with all the names in my query.

As of now I am using an array of Intersect statements using for-loops.

Eg. Find_Common of A, B, C, D, E (where Find_Common is a function I wrote to generate the relevant SQL query)

```
{DISTINCT INTERSECT A+B+C+D+E}
```

This returns NULL as ALL of the above don't have anything in common.

Eg. Find_Common of A, B

```
{DISTINCT INTERSECT A+B}
```

This returns 1,2

But ideally, I want even Find_Common of A,B,C,D,E 
should give me 1,2 (i.e. SQL should check the inner combinations of AB, ABC, ABD, etc.)

I can get the desired result if I find the combinations of my name array elements and then generate the SQL query. But I wanted to know if there is a more efficient method?

Is this possible in SQL? To be clear is it possible to have intersect on multiple queries and SQL automatically tries for intersection of combinations of sub-sets of the multiple queries?

Can anyone please guide me about this (Eg. can we do this through intersection, inner join, etc.?) or guide me to some link with the specific example so that I can study.

I have looked everywhere but not found any solution!

Best Regards,

Jogi

(sorry about the formatting. still trying to get the hang of this :) )

Hi cHao and mehdi lotfi, Thank you for your quick responses. I will try out mehdi's solution and revert asap. In the meantime, please find the additional details requested. Table columns look like this -

```
Name    King Pin    King Pin    Blackbeard  Blackbeard  Blackbeard  Blackbeard  Jackal  Jackal  Jackal  Jackal  Jackal  Jackal
MobileNumber    +919844705231   +919844702018   +919844705103   +919844701273   +919844701273   +919844704063   +919844700415   +919844705841   +919844700596   +919844705231   +919844706955   +919844706402
```

so to answer cHao's question - Each row consists of 1 name and 1 mobile number

Comment: Does this table you're talking about have one name and one number per row?  (Like, one row might be `'A', 1` and another `'A', 2`?)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use table type, and have a stored procedure with this type parameter.
you can execute your stored procedure with name list and get mobile number in coma separated format.

```
CREATE TYPE NameList AS TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(100))
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spMobileResult
    @names dbo.NameList READONLY
AS BEGIN
    SELECT STUFF(
                (SELECT DISTINCT ','+[Mobile Number]
                FROM YourTable
                WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM @Names)
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [Mobile Numbers]
END
GO

DECLARE @A dbo.NameList
INSERT INTO @A(name)VALUES('A'),('B')

EXEC spMobileResult @A
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help.

After trying the different ways, finally I went ahead with the following methodology:

1. If given an array of Names of n elements, I made an array of all the possible combination pairs using `Facet.Combinatorics` in C# as below:

   ```
   int lowerIndex = 2;
   var combinations = new Facet.Combinatorics.Combinations<String>(
       BASEstrArrNames, 
       lowerIndex, 
       Facet.Combinatorics.GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition
   );
   ```
2. Above pairs were generated on nC2 basis where n is the number of total name elements and 2 indicates pair combinations (i.e. nCr)
3. All the above generated pairs (without repetition) were stored in a holding array.
4. I found the INTERSECT on each pair and then combined all the INTERSECTS to generate a Network Graph using Arbor.js

I can't seem to post the example image of the graph as I don't have enough reputation but feel free to contact me for any assistance.